# Forwarding communication between two ports on switch

Tags: cisco, routing, switching

I have an industrial network with ring topology, consisting of a number of dumb switches and one manageable switch (Siemens OSM 62) acting like a supervisor. But now I would like to add new switch to this network. The problem is that this new switch (Stratix 5700 it's a Cisco clone) is manageable too and I'd like to force it to act as a dumb one (just to forward data from one port to another). Is there any chance how to set this new switch (using some "fancy hack") to doing this?

Thank you in advance!

Matej

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manageable switches and "dumb" switches work the same way.  A Cisco switch with default configuration (i.e., "out of the box") will forward packets just like any dumb switch.

You might have to pay attention to spanning tree if your switches are in a ring.  but we'd need more information t be sure.

Comment: the problem is that the Siemens uses some proprietary protocol to manage ring network (I think it's based on spanning tree). There is just RM (Ring Master) jumper to make him supervising whole network. And the problem is how to set this new switch when i don't know which protocol is running on network.

Comment: If your other switches are "being supervised" by the Siemens, then your other switches aren't really dumb.  What model of switches are they?

Comment: all of that switches are the Siemens one and everyone of them is the OSM 62.

Comment: After a quick perusal of the manual, it appears that the manager is the only switch running whatever protocol it uses to detect ring failures.  I'm not familiar with these switches, but my *guess* is that if you disable spanning tree on the Cisco switch, you should be able to insert it into the ring.  Perhaps someone else with more experience with these switches can say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no Configuration configured on managable cisco switches  . Cisco switches it's self acts like unmanaged switches .

So you can induct or de-induct switches  in networks  without any issue . But there is risk of inducting unmanaged switches in setup there is possibility of no loop avoidance mechanism in networks.